# No of Max Moves for any cell to get a number N

Tags: java, c#

I have an array like below
[image]

For any cell left, right, top or bottom move of current position is allowed. Cells with value blank are not allowed to visit.

Now I need all combination of length N for every cell.
Suppose for Cell[0][0] i.e A, combinations of length 3 are AAA,ADA,ABA,ADE,ABE,ADG,ABC

Please suggest any algorithm for this. I can handle for not to visit blank element and removing duplicate items.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well these kind of problems are an ideal fit for recursion.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private void visitNextNode(int pass, int maximumPass, char[][] arr, int currI, int currJ, String value){
    //Handle blank array value condition and array out of bound expception
    value +=   arr[currI][currJ];
    if(pass == maximumPass){
        list.add(value);
        return;
    }
    //Move left 
    visitNextNode(++pass, maximumPass,arr,currI-1,currJ,value);
    //Move right
    visitNextNode(++pass, maximumPass,arr,currI+1,currJ,value);
    //Move top
    visitNextNode(++pass, maximumPass,arr,currI,currJ-1,value);
    //Move down
    visitNextNode(++pass, maximumPass,arr,currI,currJ+1,value);

}
```

You can initiate the method with passvalue = 0, maximum pass as the length of the expected string, blank string value, input array and the initial start pos.

I think that should help

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working for me after making some small changes for boundary value and some custom conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final String[][] AREA = {
    {"A", "B", "C"},
    {"D", "E", "F"},
    {"G", "H", "I"},
    {null, "J", null},
};
static final int[][] MOVES = {{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}};

static boolean movable(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= AREA.length || y < 0 || y >= AREA[0].length)
        return false;
    return AREA[x][y] != null;
}

static void move(int x, int y, Set<String> result, String[] path, int i) {
    if (i >= path.length)
        result.add(String.join("", path));
    else if (movable(x, y)) {
        path[i] = AREA[x][y];
        for (int[] m : MOVES) {
            int xx = x + m[0], yy = y + m[1];
            if (movable(xx, yy))
                move(xx, yy, result, path, i + 1);
        }
    }
}

static void moves(int x, int y, int max, Set<String> result) {
    String[] path = new String[max];
    move(x, y, result, path, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    moves(0, 0, 3, result);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

result:

```
[ABA, AAA, ABB, ADD, AAB, ABC, ADE, AAD, ABE, ADG, ADA]
```